# multiple bootstrap popover on one page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I would like to use multiple popovers (more than 5...). All are dynamically added to the dom:

```
var popOverSettingsTemp = {

    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'hover',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    title: 'Temperature',
    selector: '[data-toggle="speicherInfoTemp"]',
    template: '<div class="popover speicherInfoTemp" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
    content: "<table class='table_lock table table-bordered' style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>" +
    "<tr><th></th><th scope='col'>blasenspeicher</th><th scope='col'>kolbenspeicher</th></tr>"+

    "<tr><th scope='row'>°C</th><td>-32 / +60</td><td>-32 / +60</td></tr>"+
    "<tr><th scope='row'>°C</th><td>-</td><td>-60 / +60</td></tr>"+
    "</table>",
};

var popOverSettingsAccuTemp = {
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'hover',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    title: 'Accumulator Temperature',
    selector: '[data-toggle="speicherInfoSpeicherStellfahrten"]',
    template: '<div class="popover speicherInfoSpStellfahrten" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
    content: "<table class='table_lock table table-bordered' style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>" +
    "<tr><th></th><th scope='col'>0</th><th scope='col'>1</th><th scope='col'>2</th><th scope='col'>3</th></tr>"+

    "<tr><th scope='row'>Blasenspeicher</th><td>-</td><td><i style='color: #00b789' class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></td><td><i style='color: #00b789' class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></td><td><i style='color: #00b789' class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></td></tr>"+
    "<tr><th scope='row'>Kolbenspeicher</th><td>-</td><td><i style='color: #00b789' class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></td><td><i style='color: #00b789' class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></td><td><i style='color: #00b789' class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></td></tr>"+
    "<tr><th scope='row'>ohne Speicher</th><td><i style='color: #00b789' class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td>-</td></tr>"+
    "</table>",
};
```

I add them under certain circumstances to table-elements like:

```
$('.myElement').parent().next().attr('data-toggle',"speicherInfoTemp");
        $('body').popover(popOverSettingsTemp);
```

or

```
$('.myScndElement').parent().next().attr('data-toggle',"speicherInfoSpeicherStellfahrten");
            $('body').popover(popOverSettingsAccuTemp);
```

Only the first triggered is working, the other is not.

Comment: What's your relevant HTML code section?

Comment: @EdwinKrause I simply add an attribute "data-toggle" to an element, and when I hover over that certain element it shows the content of those popovers

Comment: Why are you using `$('body').popover(yoursettings)` and not `$('[data-toggle="speicherInfoSpeicherStellfahrten"]').popover(yoursettings)` ?

Comment: it is added dynamically to the element, during runtime